# Creating a class with all the elements specified in a file using ConfigParser

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

I have created a .ini-like file with all the values which I need later in my program, see below:

```
[debugging]
checkForAbort = 10
...

[official]
checkForAbort = 30
...
```

I would like to read all these items into a single class and make it accessible from other parts of my python project.
What I have so far is the code below:

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
import glob

class ConfigurationParameters
    def __init__(self):
        self.checkForAbortDuringIdleTime = None     

    parser = SafeConfigParser()

    # making a list here in case we have multiple files in the future!
    candidatesConfiguration = ['my.cfg']
    foundCandidates = parser.read(candidatesConfiguration)
    missingCandidates = set(candidatesConfiguration) - set(found)
    if foundCandidates:
        print 'Found config files:', sorted(found)
    else
        print 'Missing files     :', sorted(missing)
        print "aborting..."


    # check for mandatory sections below
    for candidateSections in ['official', 'debugging']:
        if not parser.has_section(candidateSections)
            print "the mandatory section", candidateSections " is missing"
            print "aborting..."

    for sectionName in ['official', 'debugging']:
        for name, value in parser.items(section_name):
            self.name = value
```

I am new to python but I can still see lots of problem with my code:

- I am forced to add a attribute for each item in my class file. and keep the configuration file and my class in sync all the time.
- This class is not a singleton, therefore the reading/parsing will be done from wherever it is imported!
- If a value is added to the config-file with is not defined in my class, it will probably crash!

How should I solve this problem instead? Can class attributes be created dynamically?

My class only need to read from the values, so no writing to the configuration file is needed!

Comment: is it intentional that values from `debugging` section override corresponding values from `official`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[What J.F. Sebastian said.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12620919/395321)

Also, you could do it [like Alex Martelli does in his Bunch class](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308-the-simple-but-handy-collector-of-a-bunch-of-named/):

file `MyConfig.py`:

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser


section_names = 'official', 'debugging'


class MyConfiguration(object):

    def __init__(self, *file_names):
        parser = SafeConfigParser()
        parser.optionxform = str  # make option names case sensitive
        found = parser.read(file_names)
        if not found:
            raise ValueError('No config file found!')
        for name in section_names:
            self.__dict__.update(parser.items(name))  # <-- here the magic happens


config = MyConfiguration('my.cfg', 'other.cfg')
```

file `foo.py`:

```
from MyConfig import config
# ...
```

file `MyProgram.py`:

```
from MyConfig import config

print config.checkForAbort

import foo

assert config is foo.config
```

The [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) states that *"Import statements are executed in two steps: (1) find a module, and initialize it if necessary; (2) define a name or names in the local namespace (of the scope where the import statement occurs)."*

What that means is that, when a module gets imported, one or more local names are bound to a module object, and only the first time it is imported during the runtime of a Python program it gets initialized (i.e. read from file and run).

In the code above the name `config` is just a local name that refers to an attribute of a module object. The module object has been initialized by the Python interpreter when it was referenced (via `from MyConfig import config`) in `MyProgram`. When `MyProgram` imports `foo` it is already initialized and gets bound to a local name in module `foo` and in `MyProgram` we can refer to it as `foo.config`. But both names refer to the very *same* object.

Comment: that is certainly magic. thanks. But still the user is required to write config = MyConfiguration('my.cfg', 'other.cfg') whever he want to use an item, right? or am I totally missing something here?

Comment: 1. `.update()` accepts a dict (no need for `**`). 2. [`.update()` breaks on properties](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12620919/4279) (`setattr()` works).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: 1. Yeah, fixed. 2. I'll remember to change that as soon as I'll add properties.

Comment: @pillmuncher, I tried your code and it works well and as expected. But what exactly is __dict__. are the items stored in a dict?

Comment: `o.__dict__` for an object o is a dictionary or other mapping that contains its namespace. More about the structure of Python's objects can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__dict__). Scroll down to *"Classes"*.

Comment: I needed to implement this in an already existing class and therefore only needed the two last lines like: ```for name in section_names:
    CLASS.__dict__.update(parser.items(name))```. Thanks!

Comment: Won't this `for name in section_names:            self.__dict__.update(parser.items(name))` just overwrite [debugging] section's `checkForAbort` value with that of [official]?  I don't see how to use the dictionary built in this example...

Answer (score 3):

`self.name = value` doesn't work as you expect. You might mean `setattr(self, name, value)` It creates instance attributes dynamicallly.

To make it a singleton you could make the instance to be a global variable in `config`/`settings` module. Initialize it once on a program startup e.g., like the `logging` module does it for the root logger: `logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')`.

It is a common desire to use an attribute access for what is essentially a dict e.g., `argparse.Namespace` that carries command-line options.

You could access the config later by importing it: `from mypackage.config import config`, e.g., `mypackage/config.py`:

```
class Config(object):
    ...

config = Config() # empty or default config without any configuration
```

In `mypackage/__main__.py`:

```
from .config import config
...
# initialization code
config.update_from_file('mypackage.conf') # it might call `setattr()` inside
```

Note: `setattr()` works correctly even you set properties. `__dict__.update()` breaks in this case:

```
class XValidatorMixin(object):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError
        self._x = value


class CUpdate(XValidatorMixin):
    def __init__(self, **options):
        self.__dict__.update(options)


class CSetAttr(XValidatorMixin):
    def __init__(self, **options):
        for name, value in options.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)

for C in [CUpdate, CSetAttr]:
    o = C(a=1, b=2) # non-property attributes work as expected
    assert o.a == 1 and o.b == 2

o = CSetAttr(x=1)
assert o.x == 1 # setattr also sets property

o = CUpdate(x=1)
try:
    o.x # .update() doesn't set property
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    assert 0


try:
    o = CSetAttr(x=-1)  # invokes property setter
except ValueError: # that correctly reject negative values
    pass
else:
    assert 0
```

Comment: ok, so setattr creates attributes dynamically, that is usefull so I don´t need to declare the attributes in the class. But I really don´t undrestand what you mean in your second part of answer regarding making the class a singleton.

Comment: @theAlse: the purpose to make *an instance of a class* a singleton, not the class object itself: `config = Config(); ...` the whole program uses the same config object.

Comment: So whenever we create an instance of a class, it is global and accessible by whoever import the class?

Comment: @theAlse: No. It is not the object that is local or global, but the name with which we refer to that object. If it is defined in a function or method, then it is not global. If it is defined at module level, then it is global *in that module*. If that module gets imported somewhere via `import the_module`, then the name is not global to the importing module, since we can only refer to that object as `the_module.the_name`. If we import via `from the_module import the_name` then `the_name` is global in the namespace of the importing module.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer by [pillmuncher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12622040/1913199) is very helpful and can be easily adapted to use within an existing class. Furthermore, it is also possible to automatically convert the data types using the localconfig module ([link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/localconfig)). To get these additional functionalities you can use something like:

```
from localconfig import LocalConfig

configfile = 'config.ini'
config = LocalConfig(configfile)
sections = list(config)

for section in sections:
    items = list(config.items(section))
    CLASS.__dict__.update(items)
```