# Creating a config-class with all the sections and elements specified in a file using ConfigParser

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

Iam totally new to stackoverflow and actually I found a resolution to my excisting problem : [Creating a class with all the elements specified in a file using ConfigParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620602/creating-a-class-with-all-the-elements-specified-in-a-file-using-configparser). The given resolution of pillmuncher is nearly perfect in my case. But I need to distinguish the sections and not override everytime the corresponding values.

Is there a way to do the same class but to distuingish sections and therefore names?

Sample input (config file):

```
    [x_axis]
    speed = 1020
    ...

    [y_axis]
    speed = 1030
    ...
```

Class of pillmuncher:

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser


section_names = 'x_axis', 'y_axis'

class MyConfiguration(object):

def __init__(self, *file_names):
    parser = SafeConfigParser()
    parser.optionxform = str  # make option names case sensitive
    found = parser.read(file_names)
    if not found:
        raise ValueError('No config file found!')
    for name in section_names:
        self.__dict__.update(parser.items(name))  # <-- here the magic happens

config = MyConfiguration('my.cfg', 'other.cfg')
```

Please, even if Iam asking a total noob question, give me an hint in which direction i should look for answers.
A global config file, represented with all its sections, should not only be my conercn.

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected behavior.